# apply loaded CSS to dynamically created HTML

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm adding some HTML content dynamically using this code on a JQuery Mobile listView :

This code is being loaded in my `index.html` file withing the `#page` container

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages/notifications-list-view.css">

<div id="notifications-wrapper">
    <div class="notifications-content">

        <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar" class="notifications-categories">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="unread-notifications">
                        <span class="title">Unread notifications</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-fw"></i>
                        <span class="count">4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="all-notifications" style="height: 60px; line-height: 60px; ">All notifications</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul data-role="listview" class="notifications-list" data-inset="true">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/pages/notifications-list-view.js"></script>
```

in my `notifications-list-view.js` I have this code :

```
$("#unread-notifications").addClass ($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
fillList (4)

$("#unread-notifications").on ("click", function () {
    fillList (4);
});

$("#all-notifications").on ("click", function () {
    fillList (10);
});

function fillList (count) {
    var listItemClass = "listItem";
    var content = "";

    if (!$(this).hasClass ($.mobile.activeBtnClass)) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
            content += '<li id=' + listItemClass + '>';
            content += '<div class="delete-button"><a href="#" class="ui-btn delete-btn">Delete</a></div>';
            content += '<a href="#" class="notification-item-a">';
            content += '<div class="ui-li-thumb"></div>';
            content += '<div class="ui-li-text">';
            content += '<h3>Credit elligibility</h3>';
            content += '<p class="notification-core">';
            content += 'We have recievede  uhdccd uhc cdyucd cduhcd ucdhcd cduhcd ucdcd ucd cuhcd ucdcd ucdbcd ubc ahlan you how are you doing it\'s not good';
            content += 'We have recievede  uhdccd uhc cdyucd cduhcd ucdhcd cduhcd ucdcd ucd cuhcd ucdcd ucdbcd ubc ahlan you how are you doing it\'s not good';
            content += 'We have recievede  uhdccd uhc cdyucd cduhcd ucdhcd cduhcd ucdcd ucd cuhcd ucdcd ucdbcd ubc ahlan you how are you doing it\'s not good';
            content += 'We have recievede  uhdccd uhc cdyucd cduhcd ucdhcd cduhcd ucdcd ucd cuhcd ucdcd ucdbcd ubc ahlan you how are you doing it\'s not good';
            content += 'We have recievede  uhdccd uhc cdyucd cduhcd ucdhcd cduhcd ucdcd ucd cuhcd ucdcd ucdbcd ubc ahlan you how are you doing it\'s not good';
            content += '</p>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</a>';
            content += '</li>';

            listItemClass = "listItem" + i;
        }

        $(".notifications-list").html (content);
        $(".notifications-list").trigger ("chosen:updated");
    }
}
```

however the CSS / JS loaded previously is not applied.

How can I make the CSS style and JS code applied to this dynamically added HTML content ?

Thank you.

Comment: it should work. You should define css for the dynamic content you add. That's all you should do.

Comment: the CSS is already included in the page with `link` tag.

Comment: `$(".notifications-list").listview("refresh")`. remove `.trigger ("chosen:updated");`.

Comment: please add css you wanted to get applied,maybe problem exist there.

Comment: `however the CSS / JS loaded previously is not applied.` The CSS or JS or both???

Comment: @Omar : Thank you, I feel that I'm getting close with your code. But it gives me `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`

Comment: @A.Wolff : both, the `<div class="delete-button">` is being styled with a JS code (swipe to the left etc..)

Comment: But like suggested by @ShirinAbdolahi deleted answer, IDs must be unique. So post relevant CSS rule you want apply

Comment: isn't a listview? what's the _widget_ you're using?

Comment: @A.Wolff the id he is using is unique.cause he change it at the end of loop with `listItemClass = "listItem" + i;`

Comment: @A.Wolff jQM styles doesn't apply to dynamically added elements. An manual _enhancement_ method should be called.

Comment: @Omar, yes it is. Please take a look at my Edited question :)

Comment: Do you have more than listview with same class in DOM?

Comment: @Omar : not at all.. what does the `before initialization` means ? Thank you.

Comment: It means you're calling enhancement method before widget is created. is listview present in DOM before calling the function?

Comment: @Omar : the listview is created then the JS is interpreted, please check my updated code (all the page structure with includes)

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4au3dfxh/ with `.listview("refresh")`.

Comment: @Omar : It didn't unless I added this code : `if ($(".notifications-list").hasClass ("ui-listview")) {
   $(".notifications-list").listview ("refresh");
  } else {
   $(".notifications-list").trigger ("create");
  }` I don't know why... Please add your answer as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `.listview()` instead of `.trigger("create")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM doesn't apply styles (enhance) dynamically added elements, an *enhancement* method should be called based on *widget* used.

The problem is that you're calling `fillList()` before the page is initialized, maybe you're using `.ready()`. You should listen to jQM [*pagecontainer events*](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) to run functions.

Also, you have to understand that jQM starts enhancing *widgets* during `pagebeforecreate` event; when enhancement is done, a `pagecreate` event is fired. If you add elements dynamically during `pagebeforecreate` you don't need to call any enhancement method, however, on `pagecreate` you need to manually enhance dynamic elements, e.g. `.listview("refresh")`.

1. In `fillList()` you only need `$(".notifications-list").html(content);` when it's called during `pagebeforecreate`.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#pageID", function () {
     fillList(20);
   });
   ```
2. In `fillList()` you need to add *enhancement* `$(".notifications-list").html(content).listview("refresh")`.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
     fillList(20);
   });
   ```

When you want to call `fillList()` after page is created and shown, you will need to determine whether the *listview* is present in DOM and created.

- Fresh/New *listview*: Use `.listview()` to create it after appending it dynamically
- Existed *listview*: Use `.listview("refresh")` to apply styles to new elements