# Applying external css stylesheet to dynamically added html content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a hard time applying an external css template to dynamically added html content with jquery. I am using this HTML template and the corresponding css file: https://html5up.net/multiverse.

The html is being added to the page, but I cannot get the main.css file from the multiverse template to style the dynamically added content. The javascript code I am using is below:

```
// Paths to S3 buckets
var s3BucketURL     = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME";
var s3ThumbnailsURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME";
var JSONfile        = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/album_covers.json";

// Dynamically add HTML for images in album display
function generateAlbumCoversHTML(){
    // AJAX request to file on S3 bucket
    $.getJSON(JSONfile, function(photos) {
        // Iterate over albums and create album cover HTML
        var htmlToAdd = '';
        for (var album in photos) {
            if (photos.hasOwnProperty(album)) {
                var photo      = photos[album].split('/');
                photo          = photo[photo.length-1];
                var fullsize   = s3BucketURL + '/' + album + '/' + photo;
                var thumbnail  = s3ThumbnailsURL + '/' + photo;
                console.log(htmlToAdd);
                var html = 
                    `<article class="thumb">` +
                        `<a href=${fullsize} class="image"><img src=${thumbnail} alt="" /></a>` +
                            `<h2>${album}</h2>`+
                     `</article>`;
                htmlToAdd += html;
            }
        }
    $("#main").append(htmlToAdd);
    })
}
```

I modified the multiverse html template and deleted all the  tags within the  tag to

```
<!-- Main -->
    <div id="main"></div>
```

And from here I can append my HTML code within this div tag by calling my function at the end of the HTML code where I define all the additional javascript files I am using as

```
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">generateAlbumCoversHTML();</script>
```

Note: I have checked several references to similar problems as this one but with no luck: [apply loaded CSS to dynamically created HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380056/apply-loaded-css-to-dynamically-created-html).

Comment: Appending elements to the DOM will cause a repaint, so your CSS will (or should) be applied to the dynamically generated elements just as your static elements. See if the styles work if declared in a `<style>` tag within the document itself. If this works, I'm guessing an older version of the external CSS file is stored in your cache, preventing your browser from loading the new version containing styles for these parts. Try busting the cache by adding a bogus URL parameter, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css?v=123">`. :o)

Comment: So when I removed the <link> tag pointing to the external css from the header and added all the css manually in a <style> tag at the bottom of my index.html file, everything worked as expected! Even after busting the cache, the <link> is not formatting the dynamic content correctly. I don't mind keeping the css in a <style> tag but it seems weird that it doesn't work as expected using the <link>

Comment: At least you have a working fallback solution if all else fails (!), but this sounds really weird. Are the other rulesets in the same stylesheet working as expected or are these styles the only ones in that file?

Comment: Everything looks fine when I use the <link> and point to the stylesheet except that the image thumbnails are not filling the space they are assigned to. When I used the <style> tag and manually added the css, the image thumbnails looked great -- when I reloaded the website the images were resized incorrectly...similar to how they look when I use the <link> for the stylesheet. All the rulesets are in the external stylesheet -- the file is around 2000 lines long. This is very strange.

Comment: I noticed in the stylesheet that this css line: #main .thumb > .image {CSS STUFF HERE} is not affecting the images much at all when I mess with the properties using the <link> method...when I used the <style> method on the initial load, when I start disabling some of the properties in the #main .thumb > .image {CSS STUFF HERE} the image thumbnails are changing. For example, disabling and enabling the property background-size: cover.

Comment: You can try running the whole stylesheet through a validator to check for syntax errors - if you haven’t already?! https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 2):

CSS doesn't care if the HTML was added dynamically, don't worry about that. Your CSS either isn't loaded or is bad (you said you'd changed the template, so maybe the CSS selectors don't apply anymore).

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it seems that the css selectors are working correctly. If I console.log(htmlToAdd) and manually copy this text and add between the <div id="main"></div> tag in the index.html document, the css works as expected. Are there some quotation marks that can be silent killers here?

Comment: Hmm, actually, your `a` tag is like `<a ... /></a>` when it should be `<a ... ></a>`. Is it that?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it either. The structure of the <a> tag when I remove the <img> tag is: `<a href=${fullsize} class="image"></a>`. Is there a problem with the <img> tag?

Comment: Oh, my bad, that `/` is on the `img` and your `a` is fine. What's the value of `htmlToAdd` when you try to append it?

Comment: Sort of a mess but here it is when I do a console.log(htmlToAdd) right before I append: `<article class="thumb"><a href=https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/1 month/IMG_0318.jpg class="image"><img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-resized/IMG_0318.jpg alt="" /></a><h2>1 month</h2></article><article class="thumb"><a href=https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/birth/IMG_0134.jpg class="image"><img src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-resized/IMG_0134.jpg alt="" /></a><h2>birth</h2></article>`